# Clarity on the definition of the word "predict"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, descriptive-grammar

When someone says "I look forward to your predictable path" and "please continue down your very tired and predictable path" and "your arguments are right out of a playbook", what's the meaning of 'predictable' in this context?

Is it that they know what someone will say specifically before they say it, or they can estimate future actions or statements?

In case this saves a click, this was my understanding of the definition of the word before this question came about.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/predict

Comment: You are looking for the meaning of the word *predictable*, not the word *predict*, right? Because they are different, and one does not necessarily follow from the other. Try looking up "predictable" itself and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of "tired," the phrase "predictable path" suggests lack of creativity in charting a course.

See definition #2 here: 
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/predictable